# ng-repeat array of strings into seperate <li> elements not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects. Inside each object is an array of strings. What I'd like to accomplish is iterate over the objects with an ng-repeat but inside of that ng-repeat have another repeat to iterate over the array of strings. I would like each string to be it's own ul li element. I've read over several stackoverflow posts and my closest solution seems to iterate over the array of strings but puts them all in one 'li' element. Moving the ng-repeat from the 'li' element to the 'a' tag didn't solve this issue. Will someone look over this and tell me the correct way to get these strings to separate into different 'li' elements.

Picture of issue
[image]

Array of Objects (accessed from controller with $ctrl.websites)

```
[
  {
    id:'someID',
    title: 'First title',
    listOfTechnologies: ['KeystoneJS', 'ExpressJS', 'MongoDB']
  },
  {
    id:'anotherID',
    title: 'Second Title',
    listOfTechnologies: ['MongoDB', 'ExpressJS', 'AngularJS', 'NodeJS']
  }
]
```

HTML

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='row' ng-repeat="website in $ctrl.websites">
    <div class='col-12 col-md-6 d-none d-md-block marigold-bg'>
        <p class='sr-only'>Marigold Box</p>
    </div><!--marigoldBox-->
    <div class='col-12 col-md-6 pt-3 webProjectBox'>
        <h2 class='sr-only'>Web Projects</h2>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-3'> ...</div><!--End of col-sm-3-->
            <div class='col-9'> ...</div><!--End of col-sm-9-->
        </div><!--End of row-->
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-3'>...</div>
            <div class='col-9'>...</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row pt-3'>
            <div class='col-12 text-center'>...</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row pt-2'>
            <div class='col-12 col-md-6 text-center'>
                <a href="{{website.linkToWeb}}"><u class='view-link'><span class='h4'><i class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden="true"></i> View on the Web</span></u></a>
            </div>
            <div class='col-12 col-md-6 text-center'>
                <a href="{{website.linkToGithub}}"><u class='view-link'><span class='h4'><i class='fa fa-github' aria-hidden="true"></i> View on Github</span></u></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row pt-3'>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="nav-item m-1 animated technologies" ng-repeat="item in website.listOfTechnologies track by $index">
                <a class="nav-link btn btn-sm btn-warning disabled" href="#">{{website.listOfTechnologies[$index]}}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--Web Project Container-->
</div><!--End of row-->
</div><!--End of container-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have defined your scope through `$scope.<property>` you dont need to reference it with `$ctrl`.

created a simple [Codepen](https://codepen.io/eltonkamami/pen/VyEePg) illustrating how it can work

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="ctlr">
    <div ng-repeat="one in web">
      {{one.id}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="two in one.listOfTechnologies">
          {{two}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("ctlr", function($scope){
  $scope.web = [
  {
    id:'someID',
    title: 'First title',
    listOfTechnologies: ['KeystoneJS', 'ExpressJS', 'MongoDB']
  },
  {
    id:'anotherID',
    title: 'Second Title',
    listOfTechnologies: ['MongoDB', 'ExpressJS', 'AngularJS', 'NodeJS']
  }
];
})
```

Comment: Ok, you confirmed to me that I do have the ng-repeat in the right place and I had called it that way originally before I read about the track by id. But that led me to think the issue was that my array was not correct which looking at it in the database showed that it wasn't how I have it written here but rather all in one set of quotes. So your answer is correct if my array had been correct. Thanks.